# Python tenacity: How to retry if exception is NOT of a certain type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, python-tenacity

How to retry a function if the exception is NOT of a certain type using Python's tenacity?

`retry_if_exception_type` will retry if there is risen an exception of a certain type. `not` does not seems to work placed before the method nor before its arguments.

`retry_unless_exception_type`, on the other side, loops forever, even if there is not risen error, until there is risen error of a certain type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`retry_if_not_exception_type`](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#tenacity.retry.retry_if_not_exception_type) is available since version 8.0.0

> Retries except an exception has been raised of one or more types.

So if you use `retry_if_not_exception_type((ValueError, OSError))`, it will retry for any exception, except `ValueError` or `OSError`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create my own class for that:

```
class retry_if_exception_unless_type(retry_unless_exception_type):
    """Retries until successful outcome or until an exception is raised of one or more types."""

    def __call__(self, retry_state):
        # don't retry if no exception was raised
        if not retry_state.outcome.failed:
            return False
        return self.predicate(retry_state.outcome.exception())
```

Answer (score 0):

using `retry_unless_exception_type()` combined with `stop_after_attempt()` worked for me to accomplish this.  the `stop_after_attempt()` prevents the infinite looping.

Comment: @retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(multiplier=3, max=30), stop=stop_after_attempt(5), reraise=True,
           retry=retry_unless_exception_type(NotFoundException))

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down a bit, what you want is to retry if:

- an exception is raised
- (and) unless the exception is of a certain type

So write that:

```
retry_if_exception_type() & retry_unless_exception_type(ErrorClassToNotRetryOn)
```